# Why is the Docker platform abstraction not allowing me to run this amd64 image?

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator), their Cosmos DB docker image doesn't run on Apple Mac M1 chips. However, I'd always believed that I could run images targetting different architectures with `--platform linux/amd64` option. This work for images I've experimented with, but for the Cosmos image I get the same arch related error.

```
./palrun: ERROR: Invalid mapping of address 0x40037dd000 in reserved address space below 0x400000000000. Possible causes:
1) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) starts-up its own running environment sets the stack size limit to unlimited via syscall setrlimit(2);
2) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) adjusts its own execution domain and flag the system its legacy personality via syscall personality(2);
3) sysadmin deliberately sets the system to run on legacy VA layout mode by adjusting a sysctl knob vm.legacy_va_layout.
```

I'd like to understand why this image fails to run with `--platform linux/amd64`. Shouldn't the image be abstracted from the arm64 architecture?

Comment: Probably best to ask Azure support directly, as this is something directly related to one of their tools, and not a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a product support question.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a support question; it's technical in nature as in "why does this particular image not work with platform emulation?"; it's probably more general as to why some docker images can run with platform emulation while some cannot.

Comment: @CharlesChen - this has nothing to do with programming; it's a database emulator. It's an installable tool. At best, it would fit under SuperUser, but this is a specific caveat to the tool itself (and the docs for the emulator even illustrate the exact same error the OP is getting, pointing out the reason being related to M1). It's a support issue, and not something for Stack Overflow.

Comment: OP asked the question in the context of the emulator, but the underlying question is "why would a Docker image not work under emulation when others do?".